# Determine which Polygon Attributes are the Majority Value as Defined by Second Polygon Shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst

I need to determine the majority soil type within a series of polygons. I have data from the USDA Web Soil Survey (properly formatted and the like). I then have another shapefile with 60+ polygons outlining a series of study areas. I need to determine which soil type represents the majority soil type for each of my study area polygons.

I have Spatial Analyst and ArcGIS Advanced 10.3.1. Nothing jumps out at me regarding the appropriate way forward. To be honest, I'm not sure I'm summarizing it properly to find the proper answer via various searches.

Comment: Run Union to combine both Shapefiles, then Summary Statistics to generate max Area of Soil Type per Polygon.

Comment: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=zonalmajority is designed for this when the polygons do not overlap.

Comment: I tried the Union tool, but that simply appends the data from one polygon to another, and does not connect them in any way. I need to find a way to calculate which of the soils data represents the max percentage of area within the study area polygon.